# Erro ao tentar fazer insert no banco de dados com Laravel

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, crud

Estou utilizando o `Laravel` e já estou há um bom tempo quebrando a cabeça tentando descobrir a causa do seguinte erro ao tentar fazer um `insert`:

> (1/1) ErrorException
>   Illegal offset type
>
> in HasAttributes.php (line 818)
>
> at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Illegal offset type',
>   'C:\nisfram\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php',
>   818, array()) in HasAttributes.php (line 818)
>
> at Model->getCasts() in HasAttributes.php (line 803)
>
> at Model->hasCast('ST_ALUNO_ALU', array('date', 'datetime')) in
>   HasAttributes.php (line 832)
>
> at Model->isDateCastable('ST_ALUNO_ALU') in HasAttributes.php (line
>   565)
>
> at Model->isDateAttribute('ST_ALUNO_ALU') in HasAttributes.php (line
>   525)
>
> at Model->setAttribute('ST_ALUNO_ALU', 'Matheus') in Model.php (line
>   233)

E as mensagens de erro seguem além ainda.

Minha tabela é a seguinte:

```
Schema::create('alunos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('ID_ALUNO_ALU');
        $table->string('ST_ALUNO_ALU', 100);
        $table->string('ST_RESPONSAVEL_ALU', 100);
        $table->integer('NM_MATRICULA_ALU');
        $table->date('DT_NASCIMENTO_ALU')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Meu formulário é o seguinte:

```
<form class="form" action="{{ route('alunos.store') }}" method="POST">

   <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="ST_ALUNO_ALU" class="control-label">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ST_ALUNO_ALU" value="" autofocus>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="ST_RESPONSAVEL_ALU" class="control-label">Responsável</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ST_RESPONSAVEL_ALU" value="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="NM_MATRICULA_ALU" class="control-label">NIS</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="NM_MATRICULA_ALU" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="DT_NASCIMENTO_ALU" class="control-label">Data de Nascimento</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="DT_NASCIMENTO_ALU" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

E meu método no controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $save = Aluno::create($request->all());

    if($save)
        redirect()->back();
    else
        throw new Exception("Não foi possível registrar o aluno");            
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar já agradeço, pois eu não tenha mais ideia de onde está o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o erro. No meu model a chave primária estava assim:

```
protected $primaryKey = ['ID_ALUNO_ALU'];
```

Foi só retirar os colchetes de array que funcionou.

Comment: Sim, no seu caso deve ser um campo para chave primária, só define com `array` quando é mais de um campo.